# Oracle APEX 21.2.0 display image Primary Key

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I want to display image in report column. My table has composite primary key: ID and DATE.
When I add these columns in BLOB attributes as Primary Key Column 1 and Primary Key Column 2 report can not find data because of DATE column. Is it a problem in date format, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use only one column as a primary key column (a sequence or - if your database version supports it - an identity column).

Combination of [ID, DATE] you currently have can then be set to **unique key** (set both columns `NOT NULL` to "mimic" what primary key would do).

Why? Although your data model probably is just fine, certain Apex functionalities "suffer" from such things and prefer having a single-column primary keys.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I found one more way, I added ROWID to the query and used it as the PK in the BLOB attributes. It works fine too.

Comment: You're welcome; thank you for the ROWID hint, that's good to know; I'll try to remember it!